# Changing Radio button from vertical to horizontal alignment on new form of list

Tags: sharepoint-online, newform, choice-field

I have multiple radio buttons(choice column) on new form of a SharePoint list.

Each of my choice column contains 10 values ranging from 1 to 10(10 radio buttons) and they are displayed vertically.

What I want to do is to display all radio button horizontally in one line.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Modern or classic view?

Comment: i want it for classic view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `margin-left` CSS。

Demo:

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
        input[type="radio"] {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>

<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="edit" value="A">A
    <input type="radio" name="edit" value="B">B
    <input type="radio" name="edit" value="C">C
```

Update:

Try this JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var reBuildTR = $('<tr></tr>').append("<th></th>");
            //update RadioField as your field name
            $('table[id^="RadioField"]').find('td').each(function () {
                $(reBuildTR).append($(this));
            })
            $('table[id^="RadioField"]').html("").append(reBuildTR);
        })
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: I want to make changes in the default share point new form. I do not have a custom form.

Comment: i tried to use SPServices for the same but it does not work,i don't know why

Comment: Try the update.

Comment: do i have to change any id in the above code?

Comment: Just add the display name of your choice field instead of "RadioField" at the line `$('table[id^="RadioField"]')`

Comment: Check jQuery attribute selector https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp, it would help you understand the selector.

Comment: What if i had to do this for multiple radio button?

Comment: However, some columns are not changing